# Como usar um padleft(11) em um get na API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Esse é o método que tenho em meu MVC

```
public async Task<List<FuncionarioViewModel>> GetFuncionariosVM()
        {
            string url = $"http://localhost:56137/api/GetFuncionario";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var _funcionario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FuncionarioViewModel>>(response);   


            return _funcionario;
        }
```

Eu preciso dar m padleft(11) no campo CPF e não sei como fazer. Abaixo o método get na API

```
public class GetFuncionario
    {
        BancoContext banco = new BancoContext();

        //Método que retorna uma lista de funcionarios
        public List<Funcionario> GetFuncionarios()
        {
            return banco.Database.SqlQuery<Funcionario>("sp_cons_funcionarios").ToList();
        }
    }
```

Por ser um campo numérico, preciso de um padleft(11) para cpf que comecem com 0 ele cortar os 0 à esquerda. Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Se fizer um simples `Convert.ToInt32(funcionario.cpf);` não funciona?

Comment: Eu não tenho funcionario no Get

Comment: Então onde pretende fazer a conversão para inteiro?

Comment: Essa é a dúvida que eu postei. Como eu faria isso?

Comment: Por que precisa, isso tem cara de gambiarra e vaio dar problema, mas posso estar engando, pode explicar melhor?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar uma ViewModel de funcionário com as mesmas propriedades da entidade, mas nessa ViewModel o cpf vai ser do tipo string.

No método `GetFuncionario` você precisa mapear a entidade Funcionario para a ViewModel Funcionario, e aí, no mapeamento você dá um `funcionarioViewModel.CPF = funcionario.CPF.ToString().PadLeft(11, "0");` e retorna essa ViewModel para onde você quer.